# Merge Two Sorted Linked Lists

Tags: c++, programming-challenge, linked-list, mergesort

I solved this [problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/merge-two-sorted-linked-lists) in C++. I was having trouble though understanding what return headA; and return headB; returns after going back down the recursion tree. A code review is also appreciated!

> You’re given the pointer to the head nodes of two sorted linked lists.
>   The data in both lists will be sorted in ascending order. Change the
>   next pointers to obtain a single, merged linked list which also has
>   data in ascending order. Either head pointer given may be null meaning
>   that the corresponding list is empty.

```
/*
  Merge two sorted lists A and B as one linked list
  Node is defined as 
  struct Node
  {
     int data;
     struct Node *next;
  }
*/
#include <iomanip>

Node* MergeLists(Node *headA, Node* headB)
{
    // check if either linked list is empty, then return the other one. when doing recursive, a new headA and headB will be passed in, so it will add the entire list correctly
  if (headA == NULL) {
      return headB;
  } else if (headB == NULL) {
      return headA;
  } else { // if neither empty go into this block
      if (headA->data <= headB->data) {
          headA->next = MergeLists(headA->next, headB);
          // returns the entire linked list after the recursion parses it in the correct order
          // not too sure what is returned going down the recursion tree
          // headA = 1 -> 3 -> 5 -> 6 -> NULL
          // headB = 2 -> 4 -> 7 -> NULL
          // would it return 6, 5, 3, 1, 1->2->3->4->5->6->7 after recursion tree?
          return headA;
      } else {
          headB->next = MergeLists(headA, headB->next);
          // return 7, 4, 2 after recursion tree?
          return headB;
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is fine, subject to the caveat that the use of recursion imposes a limit on the length of your lists, due to the possibility of stack overflow.

Your comments betray a sense of insecurity about how it works, though.  Just consider what happens locally, and trust that recursion will take care of the rest.

I also suggest un-nesting the `else` block.

```
/**
 * Recursively merge two sorted lists by manipulating node pointers.
 * Returns the head of the merged list.
 */
Node* MergeLists(Node *headA, Node* headB)
{
    if (headA == NULL) {
        return headB;
    } else if (headB == NULL) {
        return headA;
    } else if (headA->data <= headB->data) {
        headA->next = MergeLists(headA->next, headB);
        return headA;
    } else {
        headB->next = MergeLists(headA, headB->next);
        return headB;
    }
}
```

Comment: Since each of your `if` blocks returns, you don't really need any of the`else`s. You can just have 3 `if`s and a default.

Answer (score 1):

**An iterative algorithm**

Of course, you can do the job recursively. However, if you merge large lists that way, there is a chance of running out the stack space. Also, the space complexity of your recursive method is \$\Theta(n)\$ (on the stack). Using iteration, you can reduce the space complexity to \$\Theta(1)\$, and that is how:

```
Node* MergeLists(Node *headA, Node* headB)
{
    if (!headA) 
    {
        return headB;    
    }

    if (!headB)
    {
        return headA;
    }

    Node* head;
    Node* tail;

    if (headA->data < headB->data)
    {
        head = headA;
        tail = headA;
        headA = headA->next;
    }
    else
    {
        head = headB;
        tail = headB;
        headB = headB->next;
    }

    while (headA && headB)
    {
        if (headA->data < headB->data) 
        {
            tail->next = headA;
            tail = headA;
            headA = headA->next;
        }
        else
        {
            tail->next = headB;
            tail = headB;
            headB = headB->next;
        }
    }

    if (headA) 
    {
        tail->next = headA;    
    }
    else 
    {
        tail->next = headB;
    }

    return head;
}
```

**Coding conventions**

You use a consistent coding style what comes to spacing, braces, etc. However, I suggest you don't use more than 80 characters on any line; for example:

```
// check if either linked list is empty, then return the other one. when doing recursive, a new headA and headB will be passed in, so it will add the entire list correctly
```

Why not split it in more than one line:

```
// check if either linked list is empty, then return the other one.     
// when doing recursive, a new headA and headB will be passed in, 
// so it will add the entire list correctly
```

Hope that helps.